# Make url so that I can also accept extra parameter in .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have goggling all around but not able to find the right solution.

I have a simple HTML site that contains only HTML files(.html extension) like pricing.html,contact-us.html etc.

I want to make url so that it accept integer as a parameter like this

Currently: http://www.amznhosting.com/pricing.html

I want to make url so that I can also accept extra parameter like this:

http://www.amznhosting.com/pricing.html/2

This is what I did so far in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pricing.html?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Its working but css,js and images are not getting load.

Anyone having any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html/(.+)$ /$1.html?params=$2 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite /file.html/path to /file.html?params=path .

Comment: Its not working on me,Its say "a 404 Not Found error".
Also I don't want query string in my URL.

I just want url like this: http://www.amznhosting.com/pricing.html/2

instead of:

http://www.amznhosting.com/pricing.html?params=2

Comment: There is no querystring in the new url. It silently redirects **/file.html/2** to **/file.html?params=2** as you mentioned in your question body.